# How to awk -F this string?

Tags: shell, awk

```
E APPL C uxcds402 0 1 .../usr/local/clo/ven/WDM/70x/gdcdc50252rdsNetwork/config gdcdc50252rdsNetwork gdcdc50252Manager dmgr
```

I saved this line into test.config.

I want to get `/usr/local/clo/ven/WDM/70x/gdcdc50252rdsNetwork/config gdcdc50252rdsNetwork gdcdc50252Manager dmgr` by `cat test.config |awk -F... '{print $1}'` but got nothing.

I also tried other methods like `awk -F\.\.\.`, but also not ok.

Could you please help me about it. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It appears like you want the second column not first. Try this:

```
$ cat test.config
E APPL C uxcds402 0 1 .../usr/local/clo/ven/WDM/70x/gdcdc50252rdsNetwork/config gdcdc50252rdsNetwork gdcdc50252Manager dmgr
$ awk -F'[.][.][.]' '{print $2}' test.config
/usr/local/clo/ven/WDM/70x/gdcdc50252rdsNetwork/config gdcdc50252rdsNetwork gdcdc50252Manager dmgr
```

or you can grab the last column by doing

```
$ awk -F'[.]' '{print $NF}' test.config
/usr/local/clo/ven/WDM/70x/gdcdc50252rdsNetwork/config gdcdc50252rdsNetwork gdcdc50252Manager dmgr
```

Answer (score 1):

If you accept other commands, use gnu grep or sed.

```
grep -Po "\.{3}\K.*" file
/usr/local/clo/ven/WDM/70x/gdcdc50252rdsNetwork/config gdcdc50252rdsNetwork gdcdc50252Manager dmgr

sed -r 's/.*\.{3}//' file
/usr/local/clo/ven/WDM/70x/gdcdc50252rdsNetwork/config gdcdc50252rdsNetwork gdcdc50252Manager dmgr
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another solution:

```
cat test.config | awk -F'(\\.\\.\\.)' '{print $2}'
```